# TYPO3: How do I set conditional values in Site Handling?

Tags: typo3

I have a system with two different domains in it: On for production and one for development. In Site Handling I am using a condition to differentiate the two.

How can I access the name of the current domain in my TypoScript setup? I want to put the domain name in the middle of a text string, which is later output in the website.

I tried defining the domain in the `settings:` section of config.yaml. But how  do I change it depending on the system I am on? I did not find a way to use a condition there. Is there a recommended way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to directly get the value from Site Configuration.

```
page.footerData.1 = TEXT
page.footerData.1.value = This is the domain: {URL}. Lorem ipsum... And here it is again: {URL}.
page.footerData.1.stdWrap.replacement {
  10 {
    search = {URL}
    replace.data = site:base
  }
}
```

That way I do not need to set the values another time - I do not need a condition. I can directly take the value from Site Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be this:

```
[request.getNormalizedParams().getHttpHost() == "domain-1.com"]
    lib.myText = TEXT
    lib.myText.value = This site is running on domain-1.com
[request.getNormalizedParams().getHttpHost() == "domain-2.com"]
    lib.myText = TEXT
    lib.myText.value = This site is running on domain-2.com
[global]
```

The conditions are listed and explained here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Conditions/Index.html

Another option is to just use the old options of TypoScript to get the current host:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.stdWrap.data = getIndpEnv : HTTP_HOST
page.10.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
page.10.stdWrap.noTrimWrap = |This site is running on ||
```

The available $_SERVER variables are listed and explained here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Functions/Data.html#getindpenv

Comment: especially in combination with `htmlSpecialChars = 1` I consider it as safe.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use environment variables. So you have per instance (production and development) an .env file in which you define a variable like

*.env for production*

```
CUSTOM_DOMAIN_VALUE="my-production-domain.com"
```

*.env for development*

```
CUSTOM_DOMAIN_VALUE="my-development-domain.com"
```

This environment variable could you use in the config.yaml with `'%env(CUSTOM_DOMAIN_VALUE)%'`. The TypoScript condition to switch between the value is not necessary.

To work with environment you could use the package [Symfony dotenv](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dotenv) or the package from Helmut Hummel [Dotenv-Connector](https://packagist.org/packages/helhum/dotenv-connector)